# Flask dynamically render scoreboard from Mysql using Ajax

Tags: python, mysql, ajax, flask

I want to make a dynamic scoreboard importing data from a MySQL query into a html table. This is my query:

```
query = db().fa('SELECT name, score '
              'FROM `GIP-Schema`.scoreboard '
              'INNER JOIN `GIP-Schema`.user ON user_id = user.id '
              'ORDER BY score DESC')
```

by the way the `fa()` is a `fetchall()` function. I can use regex if that's necessary to filter out the MySQL notation ( `(item),(otheritem),` ).

The table would use some bootstrap classes and I imagine it looking like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Score</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>{{name1}}</td>
                <td>{{score1}}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>{{name2}}</td>
                <td>{{score2}}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>{{name3}}</td>
                <td>{{score3}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

What do I need to do, to insert the MySQL data retrieved with the query into the table. Also the table should increase in number of rows based on the number of entries in the query.

Comment: Can you update your post so it poses a clear question?

Comment: sorry, forgot that little part, hah

Answer (score 0):

There are obviously many ways to do this. The easiest would be to create DOM nodes using javascript and [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) them to the page. That is probably the shortest path to get to what you're after. That sort of technique can get complicated quickly as you try to alter the DOM in more complicated ways. For example, maybe you want to also remove scores that are greater than a certain age. Coordinating this all in the success handler of an ajax call can become a bit difficult to maintain.

A more modern way to handle this sort of this is to use a javascript library to handle the DOM manipulations for you. Some popular examples are Angular, React, and Ember. They help you structure your code in a manner that's easier to maintain and, as the complexity grows, easier to wrap your head around.

Obviously you're kind of making a tradeoff here. These libraries may make a some aspects of your problem easier, but now you have a learn to use a javascript library. You very well may find that for what you're trying to do, simply appending DOM nodes manually is simpler than diving into a javascript library.

**EDIT:**

DOM nodes refer to what is created by HTML tags. For example, `<p>Hello</p>` creates a paragraph dom node. Generally the browser handles this when you load the page, but you can alter what the browser has created using javascript. To see what I mean, open your browser console (in firefox: right click -> inspect element, and then click on console). Then type the following.

```
var p = document.createElement("p");
p.innerHTML("HELLO");
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

Scroll down to the bottom of the page and you should see that you've added `HELLO` to the bottom of the page. You can do something similar when you receive data from your ajax call and either add things (DOM nodes) to the page, or remove them as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: It's for a short term project, so deleting won't be needed, it stays as simple as I explained it, I'll take a look at the DOM nodes now.

Comment: I think I may not have explained myself very well. See the edits I made above.

Comment: How do I go about linking the javascript to the python variable ?

Comment: You will have to access it in your ajax call. This is beginning to stray from the question-answer format. Do you want to try and talk more in chat?

Comment: I'd love to, can it wait a little however? i'm curently cooking :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144197/discussion-between-user2027202827-and-thom-ernst).

Comment: Sorry, not that familiar with how this works. Try that link.